# How to add the text "Choose a Category" to jquery drop-down menu

Tags: jquery

As it stands the first selection is Apple, which the first selection should be the text "Choose a Category". How do I insert this into my jquery script, only using jquery to insert it-not HTML?

Here is the jquery in question that I am trying to insert the text into:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#sub_listing_categories ul').each(function () {
        var list = $(this),
            select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function () {
                window.location.href = $(this).val();
            });
        $('>li a', this).each(function () {
            var option = $(document.createElement('option'))
                .appendTo(select)
                .val(this.href)
                .html($(this).html());
            if ($(this).attr('class') === 'selected') {
                option.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
        list.remove();
    });
});
```

The HTML is this:

```
<div id="sub_listing_categories">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Apple</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Orange</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Pear</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it with `.append('<option>Choose a Category</option>')`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#sub_listing_categories ul').each(function () {
        var list = $(this),
            select = $('<select>').append('<option>Choose a Category</option>').insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function () {
                window.location.href = $(this).val();
            });
        $('>li a', this).each(function () {
            var option = $('<option>')
                .appendTo(select)
                .val(this.href)
                .html($(this).html());
            if ($(this).attr('class') === 'selected') {
                option.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
        list.remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sub_listing_categories">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Apple</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Orange</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Pear</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I also made a couple of other minor changes like `document.createElement('select')` to `$('<select>')`

Comment: I do have 1 question- if you choose Apple from the drop-down and then click the drop-down again and select Choose a Category it gives a server error. Is there a way to hide the Choose a Category from the drop-down list?

Comment: You mean hide the Choose a Category option once a category is chosen? An alternative would be to not do anything on the click event when the Chose a Category option was selected. Come to think of it, based on your click event code, someone wouldn't be able to make a second choice after making the first choice since you're redirecting them.

Comment: Yep your absolutely right, because it directs them to the href page on click. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: But is there any way to hide the Choose a Category from the drop-down list?

Comment: No actually from the initial first click on the drop-down, it shows the Choose a Category

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you saying you want to see the choose a category option, but as soon as you click the select menu it should disappear?

Comment: Before first click it shows "Choose a Category" - then you click on the drop-down it shows "Choose a Category, Apple, Orange, Pear" - so instead of the first click showing the four above options-could first click only show "Apple, Orange, Pear"?

Comment: I don't think browsers allow that. At least not without some hacky workaround.

Comment: Cool, I think you have went above and beyond for this. I thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#sub_listing_categories ul').each(function () {
        var list = $(this),
            select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function () {
                window.location.href = $(this).val();
            });
      $(document.createElement('option'))
                .appendTo(select)
                .val('Choose a Category')
                .html('Choose a Category');
        $('>li a', this).each(function () {
            var option = $(document.createElement('option'))
                .appendTo(select)
                .val(this.href)
                .html($(this).html());
            if ($(this).attr('class') === 'selected') {
                option.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
        });
        list.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect. I really needed that, I have tried everything with no positive outcome. It seems that the answer was pretty straight forward. I will keep this little bit of code for reference in the future. Again thanks!

Comment: If it's what you need, mind choosing it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("ul").children("li").eq(0).before('<li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Choose a Category</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sub_listing_categories">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Apple</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Orange</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Pear</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps...